# how to upgrade the website to http2 php application

Tags: http2

My web application runs on https with http1.1 protocol. It was built using php5.4.27 and mysql5.0 and running on apache 2.2 in Centos 6.5 32bit system.

I want to upgrade the request protocol to http2 from http1.1 with https.

I would like to know the process for updating to http2 and supported versions for php & mysql

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by webserver not PHP or MySQL.

Your current version of Apache (2.2) doesn't handle HTTP/2 - only Apache 2.4.18 and above (but would recommend latest version as this is changing quite a bit and is still marked as experimental). Note there are quite a few differences between Apache 2.2 and 2.4.

An alternative, if you don't want to upgrade, is to stick a CDN with HTTP/2 support in front of your site. Some of them (e.g. Cloudflare) even offer free tiers with HTTP/2 support.

Comment: is php5.4.27 compatible with Apache 2.4.18?

Comment: Dunno don't use PHP myself but does look like it's end of life anyway: http://php.net/supported-versions.php